# bash echo - how to denote the end of command

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

```
NL=$'\n'
CMD=""
CMD="$CMD echo Hello ; $NL"
CMD="$CMD echo World ; $NL"
$CMD
```

The above code gives the following output, the `echo` globing everything after it.

```
Hello ; echo World ;
```

Neither the new line character nor the semicolon does work here. What is going wrong?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Look at the link @melpomene gave you. Why do you want to do it?  If you don't mind playing dangerously, explore `eval $CMD` and variants on that theme (`eval "$CMD"`, …).  Then decide to do whatever it is you are trying to do (an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?) a different way.

Comment: Assuming you went the `eval` route, you don't need newlines at all; a semicolon by itself separates two commands just fine. When `$CMD` is expanded without quotes, the newlines are just discarded anyway, but the semicolons are treated as arguments to the `echo` command (that is, the expansion is not reparsed).

Answer (score -2):

For enabling interpretation of backslash escapes you have to add -e flag to echo.

```
:/$ NL='\n'
```

Putting line feed into NL variable.

```
:/$ CMD=""
```

Setting CMD to empty string.

```
:/$ CMD="$CMD echo Hello ; $NL"
```

Resetting CMD, since old CMD is "" then new is " echo Hello ; \n"

```
:/$ CMD="$CMD echo World ; $NL"
```

Resetting CMD, since old CMD is " echo Hello ; \n" then new is " echo Hello ; \n echo World ; \n"

```
:/$ echo -e $CMD
echo Hello ; 
 echo World ;
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?